# Can the "off" color be set for a Matplotlib dashed line?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Using dashed lines is nice because it gives a way to distinguish lines that doesn't rely on the reader being able to perceive differences in color. The trouble is that they only work if the details of the line are all larger than the dash pattern. The documentation for [Matplotlib's `Axes.plot`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.plot.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.plot) function describes how to customize a line's color (with the `color` keyword) and how to customize the pattern of dashes (`dash` keyword). Is there a way to make the plot alternate between two different selectable colors instead of "there" and "not" with a single call to `Axes.plot`?

I can achieve this effect by plotting the same line twice, once with a solid line and then overplotting the same data with the dashed line, but that makes managing the alpha transparency complicated (translucent lines are desirable when there are several intersecting lines on one plot). The black and grey lines in the plot below were generated with these lines of code:

```
ax.plot(xv1, yv1, marker="None", linestyle="-", color=(0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 1.0))
ax.plot(xv1, yv1, marker="None", linestyle="--", color=(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0))
```

Edit: Another reason to desire that this be doable with a single call to `Axis.plot` is that it would display an example line correctly when creating a legend (the only remaining drawback I've found of the methods given in the answers).

[image: Example of a plot with alternating color dashed lines.]

Comment: Submitted as a [feature request issue on Github](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/18351).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This doesn't accomplish what you are asking "*with a single call to `Axes.plot`*", but the desired behavior can be created by using two custom [`linestyles`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/linestyles.html) - one of which is offset by the width of the other's dash.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0, np.pi*4, 100)
y = np.sin(x)

plt.plot(x, y, linestyle=(0, (2, 2)))
plt.plot(x, y, linestyle=(2, (2, 2)))
plt.show()
```

[image]

The `linestyle` specification is `(offset, (on_off_seq))` where `on_off_seq` is a `tuple` of one or more values, in `pt`s.

Comment: Good enough. It addresses my opacity concerns, and it can be wrapped in a function in a straightforward way.

Comment: @SeanLake Glad that works for you, depending on what you're trying to depict you might also just want to use a tighter dash and higher dpi instead of double doing this. Just a thought

Comment: I'm actually working in pdf, so the dpi is infinite. Even so, the dash-patterns miss features of these histograms without something to fill in the blanks. See, especially, the light grey peak in the middle plot.

Answer (score 6):

Experimenting a bit with @WilliamMiller's beautiful answer, this can be extended to more than two colors:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0, np.pi*4, 100)
y = np.sin(x+np.pi/2)
z = np.sin(x+np.pi/4)
w = np.sin(x)

plt.plot(x, y, linestyle=(0, (5, 5)), color='gold')
plt.plot(x, y, linestyle=(5, (5, 5)), color='crimson')

plt.plot(x, z, linestyle=(0, (10, 30)), color='blueviolet')
plt.plot(x, z, linestyle=(10, (10, 30)), color='lime')
plt.plot(x, z, linestyle=(20, (10, 30)), color='fuchsia')
plt.plot(x, z, linestyle=(30, (10, 30)), color='coral')

plt.plot(x, w, linestyle=(0, (10, 20)), color='crimson', lw=3)
plt.plot(x, w, linestyle=(10, (10, 20)), color='lime', lw=3)
plt.plot(x, w, linestyle=(20, (10, 20)), color='deepskyblue', lw=3)

plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]

Comment: This is mighty neat

Answer (score 1):

In case you want legends on your plot you can do the following:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(0, 2*np.pi, 0.2)
y = np.cos(x)

blue_line, = plt.plot(x, y, linestyle='-', lw=3)
dashed_line, = plt.plot(x, y, linestyle=(2, (2, 2)), lw=3)

plt.legend([(blue_line, dashed_line)], ['data'])
```

[image: The render result can be seen here (sorry I can't post embedded images)]

Legends in `matplotlib` are very customizable, more interesting examples and information can be seen [here](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/intermediate/legend_guide.html).